# Yammer Single Sign on with External Network

Tags: yammer

we have a requirement to enable single sign on with our external network. According to what I have read so far regarding yammer sso is that sso can only be enable on primary network. But in our case, we will be creating a new external network and associating a new domain with network. For example, we will be creating a external network with a name like "NewNetworkTest.com" then we would like to associate newnetworktest.com domain to this network and also want to enable sso particularly for this domain. IS that possible in yammer ?

Comment: This is an answer that you can best get through talking with your Yammer sales or support person. It is not a code or API question.

Comment: What you describe isn't possible with external networks. If you want another domain to be associated with a network, you need to create a new home/primary network for that domain and then perform SSO against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Yammer! SSO can only be enabled on Enterprise Primary Network.